# is it possible to insert many collections with many documents in one go?mongodb

Tags: mongodb

To break down my question:

Lets say I have 5 books, each book has details on the authors(eachbook has multiple authors), and details on when it was published.

Therefore,  i need 5 collections, one for each book, and within each collection I would need many documents on the authors, and one document on the details?

What single query would I need to insert data into 4 of these books at the same time?

i'm using mongodb

Answer (score 2):

That would be a very unusual MongoDB configuration. Typically, additional *collections* are not created in the regular course of database interactions, only *documents*.

It would be much more performant to have one collection called 'Books' and each book would be its own document within that collection.

You could create an author as a sub-document within each book document, but that would be a lot of writes and cumbersome to maintain if there are changes.

In this case, it would be best to apply a more Relational Database type strategy and have a separate collection called 'Authors', containing a document with the details of each author. You could then store an array of author IDs on corresponding books and use the **$lookup** method to join Author data on Book data.

Inserting many documents in one go is no problem. The method depends on what MongoDB driver you are using. In JavaScript/Node.js for example, **insertMany()** accepts an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Multiple Documents
collection. insertMany() can insert multiple documents into a collection. Pass an array of documents to the method. If the documents do not specify an _id field, MongoDB adds the _id field with an ObjectId value to each document.

```
db.collectionName.insertMany([{_id:1,name:raj},{_id:2,name:ashwin}])
```

you can insert manny documents like this . _id is optional if you not take it then _id will automatically generated.